# Thread submit a task and do not wait for completion in spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am writing a service where I want to expose an endpoint which will call another service and if the service call is successful then I want to send back the result to UI/ calling app.

In parallel before sending back the response, I want to execute/submit a task which should run in background and my call should not be dependent on success or failure of this task.

Before returning the response i want to do the-

```
executorService.execute(object);
```

This should not be a blocking call..

Any suggestion

Comment: Have a look at Spring Async methods: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: @Async
  public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(String user) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Looking up " + user);
    String url = String.format("https://api.github.com/users/%s", user);
    User results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
  } .    this is not helping as its returning interim result

Answer (score 4):

Spring Async methods is the way to go here as was suggested in comments.

Some caveats:

1. Async methods can have different return types, its true that they can return CompletableFuture but this is in case if you called them from some background process and would like to wait/check for their execution status or perhaps, execute something else when the future is ready. In your case it seems that you want "fire-and-forget" behavior. So you should use `void` return type for your `@Async` annotated method.
2. Make sure that you place `@EnableAsync`. Under that hood it works in a way that it wraps the bean that has `@Async` methods with some sort of proxy, so the proxy is actually injected into your service. So `@EnableAsync` turns on this proxy generation mechanism. You can verify that this is the case usually in the debugger and checking the actual type of the injected reference object.
3. Consider customizing the the task executor to make sure that you're running the async methods with executor that matches your needs. For example, you won't probably want that every invocation of async method would spawn a new thread (and there is an executor that behaves like this). You can read about various executors [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) for example

**Update**

Code-wise you should do something like this:

```
public class MyAsyncHandler {

    @Async
    public void doAsyncJob(...) {
      ...
    }
}

@Service 
public class MyService {
  @Autowired // or autowired constructor
  private MyAsyncHandler asyncHandler;

  public Result doMyMainJob(params) {

     dao.saveInDB();
     // do other synchronous stuff
     Result res = prepareResult();
     asyncHandler.doAsyncJob(); // this returns immediately
     return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: 0


yes i want result to be returned to ui and then want to make a after that .. and it will be fire and forget

Comment: also can we submit excutor.excute() to asyn method i tried but  CompletableFuture.runAsync( pre...); but it does not take executorService as object

Comment: Async methods encapsulate the work with executors (you can also work directly with executors, but then you miss the "async" goodies. I've updated the answer to give you an idea how your code will look like. I suggest trying this out first and checking the result by yourself

Comment: Thanks For your resposne its helpful.. just one thing -@Async
    public void doAsyncJob(...) {
      ...
    } .   this will spwan a new thread suppose i want to do my task by spwaing 5 thread ... thn .          private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 
  @Async
     public void doAsyncJob(...) {
   executorService.execute(pre);
     } .     then do u see any flaw in this approach ???

Comment: It won't spawn a new thread but reuse a thred pool of your choice (you know, spawning new thread every time is expensive) but for that you should configure the task executor bean. You should read more in-depth documentation about async. Again, its the same as using executors by youself but the code is much cleaner with @Async aproach

Comment: Tested the above code .  asyncHandler.doAsyncJob(); // this returns immediately
    rhis does not return immediatly... it waiting for job to complete then returning the resp

Comment: Read carefully my original answer especially item 2 ;) the chances that async is not enabled...